# An upper bound of Jacosbthal's function

Tags: number-theory

Recently I read some paper about Jacosbthal's function $g(n)$, which is the smallest positive integer $j$ such that among every $j$ consecutive integers there exists an integer coprime to $n$. The explicit formular for $g(n)$ have not been found yet, and I really like the upper bound $$g(n) \leq 2^k$$
with $k$ is the number of prime divisor of $n$. I know this bound seems very weak, since there are a lot of stronger bounds have been found recently.I believe that we can find a simple solution for that bound. In all of my paper, they just present the inequality, without any of the proof. Can anyone know how to prove it or have any problem which is related to it?

I'm thankful about your hint in any advance.